# PIVOT function returning NULL values and ISNULL not removing

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a query using PIVOT function that has NULL values that wish to replace with 0 in the cell. I have tried to add the ISNULL into the sub query against O7CRAM but that did not remove the NULL values

```sql
    select
        * 
    from 
    (
      select 
      O7ORNO,
      O7CRID,
      O7CRAM
    
      from MVXJDTA.OOLICH 
    ) src
    pivot
    (
      sum(O7CRAM)
      for O7CRID in ([PNP], [DTY], [HAN])
    ) piv
     order by O7ORNO;
```

The issue I have now is the `ISNULL` and where to place it to remove the `NULL` values.

Current Output:

| O7ORNO | PNP | DTY | HAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100000329 | 0.85 | NULL | NULL |

Desired Output:

| O7ORNO | PNP | DTY | HAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100000329 | 0.85 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

Comment: Add the `ISNULL` to an outer query instead.

Comment: In other words, expand the "*" to individual column names in the outer query and use ISNULL on those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do the same thing with the ancient, arcane, but simple "Black Arts" method known as a CROSSTAB.  Notice how you do NOT neet explicit ISNULL()s.

```
--===== Same as the PIVOT
 SELECT  O7ORNO
        ,PNP = SUM(IIF(O7CRID = 'PNP',O7CRAM,0)
        ,DTY = SUM(IIF(O7CRID = 'DTY',O7CRAM,0)
        ,HAN = SUM(IIF(O7CRID = 'HAN',O7CRAM,0)
   FROM MVXJDTA.OOLICH
  GROUP BY O7ORNO
  ORDER BY O7ORNO
;
```

Here's a slightly different take with row/column totals and a grand total.

```
--===== Same as the PIVOT with row/column totals and grand total
 SELECT  O7ORNO
        ,PNP = SUM(IIF(O7CRID = 'PNP',O7CRAM,0)
        ,DTY = SUM(IIF(O7CRID = 'DTY',O7CRAM,0)
        ,HAN = SUM(IIF(O7CRID = 'HAN',O7CRAM,0)
        ,RowTotal = SUM(O7CRAM)
   FROM MVXJDTA.OOLICH 
  GROUP BY O7ORNO WITH ROLLUP
  ORDER BY GROUPING(O7ORNO),O7ORNO
;
```

For more information about how CROSSTABs work and for how to make Dynamic CROSSTABS, please see the articles at the following links:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/cross-tabs-and-pivots-part-1-converting-rows-to-columns-1

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/cross-tabs-and-pivots-part-2-dynamic-cross-tabs

Comment: Wouldn't `ORDER BY GROUPING_ID( O7ORNO )` be better than `ORDER BY GROUPING( O7ORNO )`?

Comment: I could certainly be wrong but I don't see an advantage of using the GROUPID_ID() function here especially since there's only 1 level of aggregation.  If you know of an advantage that I'm not seeing, please let me know because you have my honest interest.

Comment: @JeffModen - your proposed solution worked perfectly.  I was able to use this directly in another report I am building that is quite large and complex and using this simplified version instead of a pivot made things simpler to finalize the report :).  Happy Days.

Comment: @KCS - Awesome and thank you for the great feedback.  Would you mind up-voting the post?

Comment: @KCS - Thank you for the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Using the PIVOT syntax, the `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` needs to be done in the outer query.

> ```
> select O7ORNO, 
>  isnull(PNP, 0) as PNP,
>  isnull(DTY, 0) as DTY, 
>  isnull(HAN, 0) as HAN
> from (
>   select O7ORNO, O7CRID, O7CRAM
>   from MVXJDTA.OOLICH 
> ) src
> pivot (
>   sum(O7CRAM) 
>   for O7CRID in (PNP, DTY, HAN)
> ) pvt
> order by O7ORNO;
> ```

> | O7ORNO | PNP | DTY | HAN |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 100000329 | 0.85 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=74def41ddd571b24ddc445ca8bb0d7c8)*

Conditional aggregation is another method for pivotting.

```
select O7ORNO
, SUM(CASE O7CRID WHEN 'PNP' THEN O7CRAM ELSE 0 END) AS PNP
, SUM(CASE O7CRID WHEN 'DTY' THEN O7CRAM ELSE 0 END) AS DTY
, SUM(CASE O7CRID WHEN 'HAN' THEN O7CRAM ELSE 0 END) AS HAN
from MVXJDTA.OOLICH  
group by O7ORNO
order by O7ORNO;
```

Comment: your solution also worked but added a little complexity to the report i was building and the solution provided by JeffModen helped simplify it and enabled me to finish my report

Comment: That's good. So I guess you included the grouping then.  This solution's second query is basically a standard SQL version of  Jeff's first query. *(`IIF` isn't standard)*